# Time Capsule beeping on disk access

Tags: time-capsule

My 2 TB, 3rd generation Time Capsule just started making a beep-like noise today. I bought it about 30 months ago.

It beeps only when I do some disk access, e.g. when I access the filesystem remotely. Using it as a wifi router does not make it do any noises.

What should it be?

Edit: after 2 weeks with my Time Capsule beeping on every disk access, suddendly after a restart it just stoped. I restarted it before, but it had no effect, I have no ideia why it worked this last time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe some hard drives that are SMART enabled (all drives Apple use are) will beep when they detect the SMART status is failing. Perhaps open Airport Utility to check the health of the drive. I would suggest copying any data off the drive now before it fails.